# Facebook login - LoginViewController to NavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

It feels like i have been in every corner of the internet, trying to find a good tutorial example of a facebook login which has one simple login view controller that parses data to another viewcontroller AND is using storyboards, not xib files.

To be clear, what i am looking for is a tutorial, involving a LoginViewController, another viewcontroller inside a navigationcontroller which recives the userdetails from the loginViewController, using a NSDictionary with user.id, name and age. The LoginViewController also needs to push view to the navigationController.

I have checked the samples but neither of the works they way i want it to.

I cannot seem to find one or do it myself, most likely do to my inexperience with iOS/Objective C.

Does anyone have a good example, tips or tutorial for this?

Comment: here is the [facebook developer tutorial link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/)